# The difference in からandに as location markers in the following

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-から

In the sentenced circled below "The 100 yen coin is found under the desk", It usesから to mark the location.   [image]

so this made me wonder "oh! if it's used like this, then certainly に should work to as it's also a location marker!" But when I looked for answers on "HiNative" they told me It's not natural, but when asked why they didn't know how to answer me. Here's the thread in question: https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/13891892

so Any information on this is greatly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

机の下から見つかった implies that the coin was picked up, or is to be. On the other hand, 机の下に見つかった implies that it's to be fixed there. Basic sense of に is attachment or contact.

Comment: Whoa seriously? I had no idea there was a sense of Attachment or contact with に, Thank you so much! You're the first one to explain it to me this way!